# deadlock in producers/consumers queue

Tags: c++, synchronization, queue, pthreads, mutex

I try to solve one interesting problem which is described below:

> Write a console application which has N producers (N=1…10), M
>   consumers (M=1…10) and one data queue. Each producer and consumer is a
>   separate thread and all threads are working concurrently. Producer
>   thread sleeps 0…100 milliseconds randomly then it wakes up and
>   generates a random number between 1 and 100 and then puts this number
>   to data queue. Consumer thread sleeps 0…100 milliseconds randomly and
>   then wakes up and takes the number from the queue and saves it to the
>   output ‘data.txt’ file. All numbers are appended in the file and all
>   they are comma delimited (for example 4,67,99,23,…). When producer
>   thread puts the next number to data queue it checks the size of data
>   queue, and if it is >=100 the producer thread is blocked until the
>   number of elements gets <= 80. When consumer thread wants to take the
>   next number from data queue and no elements in it, consumer thread is
>   blocked until new element is added to data queue by a producer.
>
> When we start application we need to insert the N (number of
>   producers) and the M (number of consumers) after which program starts
>   all threads. It should print current number of elements of data queue
>   in each second. When we stop program it should interrupt all producers
>   and wait for all consumers to save all queued data then program exits.

To solve this except all I wrote the thread-safe queue

```
template <class T>
class global::safe_queue
{
    private:
        sync* m_sync;
        size_t m_lcorner;
        size_t m_rcorner;
        std::queue<T> m_data;

    public:
        safe_queue(sync* snc, size_t lcorn, size_t rcorn) :
            m_sync(snc),
            m_lcorner(lcorn),
            m_rcorner(rcorn) {}
        ~safe_queue()
        {
            m_sync->lock();
            while (m_data.size()){
                m_data.pop();
            }
            m_sync->unlock();
        }

        size_t size() const
        {
            m_sync->lock();
            size_t sz = m_data.size();
            m_sync->unlock();
            return sz;
        }

        size_t front() const
        {
            m_sync->lock();
            T item = m_data.front();
            m_sync->unlock();
            return item;
        }

        void push(T item)
        {
            m_sync->lock();
            while(m_data.size() >= m_rcorner) {
                m_sync->unlock();
                usleep(5);
                m_sync->lock();
                // conditional wait
                //m_sync->wait();
            }
            m_data.push(item);
            if(m_data.size() == 1) {
                m_sync->unlock();
                // conditional signal
                //m_sync->signal();
            }
            m_sync->unlock();
        }

        T pop()
        {
            m_sync->lock();
            while(m_data.size() == 0) {
                m_sync->unlock();
                usleep(5);
                m_sync->lock();
                // conditional wait 
                //m_sync->wait();
            }
            T item = m_data.front(); 
            if(m_data.size() <= m_lcorner) {
                m_sync->unlock();
                // conditional signal    
                // m_sync->signal();
            }
            m_data.pop();
            m_sync->unlock();
            return item;
        }
};
```

But as a result I get deadlock. What is wrong ?

Comment: There is double unlock here, which means on thread might unlock something locked by another and all the hell breaking loose. It is a bad error, but it should not cause a deadlock.

Comment: ok, but when I open commented lines (waint/sync) and close lock/unlock in while/if scopes I alos get deadlock when try to interrupt the program by SIGINT. In my code I have used pthread_cancel to close threads but after cancells it hanged in pthread_join()'s.

Comment: Is it possible that after pthread_cancel the mutex can stay in locket state ?

Comment: Why are you not using RAII to manage locking and unlocking the mutex?

Comment: I agree with you but on the other hand I try to use my code just for interesting.

Comment: If you pthread_cancel a thread holding mutex, and thread has not released it in it's cleanup handlers, the mutex is guaranteed to remain locked.

Comment: Please can you give some example/link how to use cleanup handler, because I don't know how to use two handlers together one for SIGINT and other for cleanup.

Comment: Search for dining-philosophers problem